# Quicksort in Java

Tags: java, quicksort

I'm supposed to do a quicksort algorithm in java to sort the array {50, 20, 65, 30, 75, 25, 90}. Here is what I have so far:

```
public class QuickSort {
public static int partition(int arrayName[], int down, int up){
    int i = down, j = up;
    int temp;
    int pivot = arrayName[(down + up) / 2];

    while (i <= j){
        while (arrayName[i] < pivot)
            i++;
        while (arrayName[j] > pivot)
            j--;
        if (i <= j){
            temp = arrayName[i];
            arrayName[i] = arrayName[j];
            arrayName[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;

        }
    }
    return i;

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] arrayName = {50, 20, 65, 30, 75, 25, 90};

    System.out.println(partition(arrayName, down, up)); 

}
}
```

I'm getting an error on the print statement (seem to have a lot of trouble with these) that says down and up cannot be resolved to variables. How can I fix it so I can successfully print the sorted list?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: you're getting an error on that line because the variables "down" and "up" are not defined in the static scope of the class. They are defined only within the "partition" method. You'll need to pass actual values into the method, or define local variables in the "main" method called "down" and "up".

Comment: The **very first thing** your fingers should do after typing "I get an error" or "I get an exception" is to start typing the **exact** error message you're getting, along with any other information like line numbers or memory addresses. If you don't do so, it makes it much harder for others to spot the error in your code, and making it harder for us makes it slower for you to get your answer. Please remember we can't see your screen or read your mind from here; it's much easier if you provide us with the information. :)

Comment: You're right. my bad. Wasn't really thinking. I edited my OP to fix this.

Answer (score 6):

It's because you haven't defined any variables named `down` and `up` in your `main` method. You should specify values instead of those names.

Comment: Thank you, it's working now. How would I go about printing out the whole sorted array instead of just the i?

Comment: No probs. To print your array, check out Arrays.toString (int[])

Comment: I put: System.out.println(Arrays.toString(partition(arrayName, down, up))); but I get an error that says: "The method toString(long[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (int)"

Comment: Try `System.out.println (Arrays.toString(arrayName));` ;o)

Comment: If this solutions works for you, you should mark it as the 'best answer'. Not only is it the nice thing to do, but it also means that other users are more likely to help you if they know you will give them upvotes in return.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting index out of bound ,

because `up` and `down` are non initialized and in java it makes them `0`

so down goes at `j` :

```
while(arrayName[j]<pivot){ //<--- this will thow exception as j starts at 0
  j--;
```

which leads to -1 and accessing the array at `arrayName[-1]` is out of bound.

Comment: This isn't necessary in Java; the language and libraries will handle this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `partition` method returns an `int`. Instead, change your method body so that it returns the newly sorted array (and make sure you change the return type in the method declaration too, else you'll get an error). Furthermore, you need to define `up` and `down` in the `main` method.

For instance:

```
public static int[] partition(...)
{
...
return arrayname;
}
```

Edit: furthermore, you may need to use `Arrays.toString()` to output the array correctly (it's been a while since I used Java). eg:

`System.out.println(Arrays.toString(partition(arrayName, up, down)));`

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem. Even though the method returns an int, it performs sorting on the reference of the array, so he should be able to print the array after partition is called. Although the implementation of partition is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for the print statement, however I am getting an error when trying to use it. It underlines the toString part and says: The method toString(long[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: Ahh, I see. That print statement would have been based on the changes to your `partition` method I mentioned earlier. To get around this, simply remove the method call from inside the .toString method, and instead just put the instance of `arrayName`.
`System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayName));`
The reason it's throwing an error is because your `partition` method returns an int, where `Arrays.toString` requires an array. Hope this helps.